# Graduall typing in TypedRacket

Tags: typed-racket

Why is TypedRacket considered gradually typed? If I understand correctly, the typechecker just sometimes knows how to infer types. And, as it seemed to me, this is not considered gradully typed, because in the end our entire program turns out to be typed, isn’t it?